# Items totaling NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a codecademy.com tutorial where we're building a cash register. I'm supposed to make the necessary tools to void a last transaction of the cash register. Therefore, I added

1. a property called lastTransactionAmount
2. a further line of code to the function 'add' to set the last transaction amount
3. a function voidLastTransaction amount that subtracts the last transaction from the total
4. then I tested the void last transaction function at the bottom (which I expect to void the four chocolates
5. then I tried to add three chocolates

When I run the code, I get

> Your bill is NaN

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
var cashRegister = {
    total:0,
    //Dont forget to add your property
    lastTransactionAmount: 0,         //this is a property I added

    add: function(itemCost) {
        this.total +=  itemCost;
        this.lastTransactionAmount = this.itemCost; //I added this to save 
    },
    scan: function(item,quantity) {
        switch (item) {
        case "eggs": this.add(0.98 * quantity); break;
        case "milk": this.add(1.23 * quantity); break;
        case "magazine": this.add(4.99 * quantity); break;
        case "chocolate": this.add(0.45 * quantity); break;
        }
        return true;
    },
    //Add the voidLastTransaction Method here // I made this function to void l
    voidLastTransaction: function() {
        this.total = this.total - this.lastTransactionAmount; 
    }
};

cashRegister.scan('eggs',1);
cashRegister.scan('milk',1);
cashRegister.scan('magazine',1);
cashRegister.scan('chocolate',4);

//Void the last transaction and then add 3 instead
cashRegister.voidLastTransaction();              //I'm voiding last transaction
cashRegister.scan('chocolate', 3);             //trying to add 3 (instead of 4)chocolate

//Show the total bill
console.log('Your bill is '+cashRegister.total);
```

Comment: @sshekhar I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: @sshekhar: It *is* defined in the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no property `itemCost` in `cashRegister`. It should be `this.lastTransactionAmount = itemCost;`

Comment: You'll get my +1 after you change the word "variable" to "property".

Comment: Done. I'm new at javascript and sometimes get confused with the terms.